# How to set a state value based on another state value using a function in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-state-management

I want to set a state value based on another state value. There are similar questions like this. But none of them satisfies my need.

So, here is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Form extends Component {
    state = {}

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            a: "somevalue",
            b: this.someFunc()
        };
      }

      someFunc(){
        if(this.props.value=="something"){
          return "value1"
        }else{
          return "value2 "+this.state.a;
        }
      }

    render() { 
        return (<h1>{this.state.b}</h1>
        );
    }
}
 
export default Form;
```

Currently the output returned is **value2 undefined**. I want this to **value2 somevalue**. How can I achieve this?

Comment: when you do `b: this.someFunc()`, `a` value has not even set yet. passing params in someFunc should fix the code `someFunc(props.value, "somevalue")`, these params can be optional when using outside constructor. As you can fallback to use `this.props.value` if not provided. Anyway, for the code above, it is better to have `const b = this.someFunc();` execute in `render()`

Comment: @AllenWong I cant use `const` as  I need a stateful component. And, there is an Event Listener on `a` here which I have not mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a lifecycle method to update the state property `b`.

```
    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
          b: someFunc()
        })
    }
```